# Devise - reset password form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having issues with the form method being post and not put/patch when changing a new

```
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
end
```

would generate the following HTML

```
<form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/users/password\" class=\"form-horizontal\" id=\"new_user\" method=\"post\" role=\"form\"><div style=\"display:none\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"TOKEN" /></div></form>
```

For my user routes, I used `devise_for :users` and the routes related to password is

```
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
```

When I click reset password, it actually points me to the create action not the update action.

Any specific reason for it?

Comment: Try changing the `url` to `edit_user_password_path(...)`.

Comment: @Bongs I tried that and it would still generate the `method=\"post\". I figure it is because form_for will generate the url based on the resource object type, whether it is persisted or new_record and will add the right method tag. But looking around, not everyone is having the issue and I check the routes generated in the #devise codebase, the create route would not have the path generated

Comment: It is fine if it still generates `method='post'`. Just check where it submits the form after clicking reset password. Also check server logs.

Comment: it submits the form, but goes to the #create action and not the #update action of the password controller, because i'm trying to reset the password for an user who forgot password

Comment: Can you provide the complete reset form code? Do you have anything like `method: "post"` or similar on submit button in the form?

Comment: Can you post the logs from what happens after you click on reset password .

Comment: After testing out on another machine locally, this issue does not happen anymore, thus I shall close the thread. Thanks for the help!